# How to use "strtoupper" function in Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have some text input filed in my application.i want to save all data in upper case. 
how can i use "strtoupper" function in cake php before saving my data ?

Comment: Just use it, what's the problem? Does it not work in CakePHP?

Comment: just use it, cakephp doesn't have restriction on it. let us know if any error OR problem

Comment: I dont know anything about cake php...but you can use strtoupper where you are passing the data as parameter

Comment: in my view file -  form input :<?=$this -> Form -> input('q2_village_maholla', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'required' => 'required', 'style' => 'text-transform: uppercase')) ?>   can you help me by an simple example :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to convert all data for a specific field within a model to upper case before saving you should use the beforeSave filter in CakePHP

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data['Model']['field']) {
        $this->data['Model']['field'] = strtoupper($this->data['Model']['field']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks :D :D :D - Mike Jenkins